# How to use a file system on a flash chip with 256KB erase sectors

Tags: filesystems, embedded

I have been asked to help out on an embedded firmware project where they are trying to mount a file system on an SPI flash chip (Cypress S25FL512S) with a 256KB (Kilo Byte) Erase sector size.

My past experience with file systems is that the file system has a block size upto 4Kbytes which is mapped onto erase sectors of 512bytes to 4Kbytes

The embedded controller is a small NXP device running at 180MHz with 512KBytes of RAM so I cannot even cache an erase sector.  I note that the chip family does have pin compatible devices with smaller erase sectors.

My general question is how do you mount a file system with a block/cluster size that is smaller than the flash erase sector size?  I've not been able to find any articles addressing this.

Comment: I agree with what you alluded to: the erase sector size is too large for this application - 256K is quite large, 4K is typical. Also, your last paragraph seems to be backwards.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart. I've edited the last paragraph thanks.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart 4k erase block size is not typical in large storage non-volatile chips.   They're typically 128KB or 256KB for the larger storage devices.   If it's smaller (like on SD cards), then there's a controller inside that's doing a translation layer and managing the physical hardware while presenting a virtual erase block to the interface.

Comment: Did you found a solution ? I have the same problem

Comment: @ransh The accepted answer below confirmed my suspicions that the large erase sector could not be easily accommodated in the small MCU to use as a traditional file system. We were looking to use the flash chip for Logging events so in the end we hand built a simple journaling type logging module that simply hard allocated N sectors, wrote the next event entry to the end of the log, and rotated round the sectors erasing the next sector when the current one was full.  We then reproduced this a number of times to fit our needs.  Not the answer to my original question but an adequate work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in any sensible way. Your specification needs to be modified.

Possible solutions are:

- Pick a flash/eeprom circuit with smaller erase size.
- Pick a flash/eeprom with more memory and multiple segments, so that you can back-up the data in one segment while programming another.
- Add a second flash circuit which mirrors the first one, erase one at a time and overwrite with contents of the other.
- Pick a MCU with more RAM.
- Backup the flash inside MCU flash (very slow and likely defeats the purpose of having external flash to begin with).

Comment: Thanks, that was my fear but I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Filesystems are made with these sorts of NAND flash commonly.  Search for 'flash file system' or 'flash translation layer' in your favorite search engine.  JFFS (and JFFS2) are common in Linux.   There's other solutions for bare metal.